# MYSQL select with a big doubt!

Tags: mysql

I've got a question about selection on my query.
I've got 2 tables. One is my **gallery** which contains gallery names, infos, etc., and another table called photos which contains the files (pics).

Ok, but I want select only 8 pics from any gallerys. 
I explain:
My query is like this:

```
 SELECT distinct gallery.gallery_id,
                 gallery.file 
 FROM photos 
 WHERE gallery_id IN(3,4)
 ORDER BY gallery_id
```

But my query return all files(pics) from my gallerys ids.
And doesn't produce results with only put limit...
How can I select only 8 pics (gallery.file) distinct from any gallery?

Any helps will be appreciate.

Klauzito

Answer (score 1):

Put the `LIMIT` clause

```
SELECT distinct gallery.gallery_id,gallery.file 
from photos where gallery_id IN(3,4) order by gallery_id LIMIT 8
```

Comment: Ok, but as I wrote, with simple limit, I only have 8 results. I want 8 pics from any gallery.

Comment: @user - Do you mean that you want 8 pics from **each** gallery?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct gallery.gallery_id, gallery.file
FROM photos
WHERE gallery_id IN (3,4)
ORDER BY gallery_id
LIMIT 8
```

This will pick only the top 8 results.

Comment: It won't, I suggest you test the query before posting it. "TOP" isn't an operator in MySQL.

Comment: Can't always test the query on the exact same interface as the user who posted.  I only have Oracle and Sybase where I'm at, it was a simple mistake.

Comment: Ok, but as I wrote, with simple limit, I only have 8 results. I want 8 pics from any gallery.

Comment: If you want pictures from any gallery remove your WHERE gallery_id IN (3,4).

Comment: No doesn't work. I think to do 2 querys. Is the best way to do my results. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(g.gallery) gallery, p.file file FROM photos p 
INNER JOIN gallery g on p.gallery_id = g.id
ORDER BY g.id
LIMIT 8;
```

Comment: Ok, but as I wrote, with simple limit, I only have 8 results. I want 8 pics from any gallery.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct gallery.gallery_id, gallery.file FROM photos WHERE (gallery_id=3 || gallery_id=4) ORDER BY gallery_id limit 8
```

I dont know whether your need is this one r not.! but., i can tell you one thing. you are saying that you want to take 8 pics from any gallery then why you need to compare gallery id with picture table. simply you can take 8 pics from picture table know..? i think you have to tell your needs little clearly bro.